# Touchpad gets disabled if notebook removed from dock

Tags: touchpad

I have a T430 with CentOS 6.4 used as a Desktop. If I remove it from its dock, the touchpad isn't working anymore.

**My question**: How to debug/solve this problem??

Comment: What does `dmesg` say? Are you using the eject button on the docking station before un-docking?

Comment: Please find the relative hardware key for activating/disabling the touchpad (Fn + F1-F12, maybe some other combination), and try it few times see what happens and watch what it spits to `dmesg`. You could boot Fedora 20 Live Image and test the behaviour there too. Please provide tests info along with `dmesg`.